# How can I split a footer/header into multiple cells in Cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

When adding a footer or header (group footer or overall/list page footers) it's created as a single Data Item cell. It's impossible to add any Insertable Objects into the footer/header and I'm not seeing any way to split the cell/add more cells from the right click menu or the Properties of the cell.

How can I split a footer or header into multiple Cells in Cognos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split a footer or header you need to select the footer/header and then go into the **Structure** menu, under the **Headers & Footers** submenu and select **Split List Row Cell**.

Here's the location of the menu in Cognos 8:

[image: Structure menu, Headers & Footers, then Split List Row Cell]

You can now change the data/text/whatever item in each individual cell for each header or footer.

Note splitting will split your footer into one cell per list item in the report; if you have 4 list items, you'll get 4 cells. You can Ctrl+click to select multiple footer cells, then use Merge List Row Cells from that same menu to merge cells, leaving you with exactly the amount of cells you want.

I found this out and some more info on headers & footers [from IBM's documentation.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.8.4.0.doc/ug_cr_rptstd_id22012cr_rptstd_frmat_rep_add_header_or_f.html)

Comment: There is also a toolbar button that does the same thing.