# How can I turn a footer cell into a data container?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I've got a split footer I made via [How can I split a footer/header into multiple cells in Cognos?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12480915/869458), but I need one of the split cells to be a Data Container.

Here's the footer/list items:

[image]

I actually want Location Count in the right column and a Text item in the left column as a label.

When trying to drag a query item into the right footer cell, I get this error: "This object can only be inserted into a data container"

[image: IBM Cognos 8 Report Studio. This object can only be inserted into a data container.]

Here's the properties list of the left item and right item respectively:

[image]
[image]

How can I turn this footer cell into a Data Container or otherwise allow me to set those "Text Source" properties to allow it to accept a data item from a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done, after you press the unlcok button on the toolbar. 
From locked state: 
[image: Locked]

To unlock state: 
[image: Unlock]

Now, you can easily drag items from cell to another and drag query items into the cells.